# Visual Studio Xamarin Install problems

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I am having a heck of a time getting Xamarin working in VS 2015. I went through the installation process easily, but when I tried to build a simple project from the template (I've added no code). I get all sorts of errors having to do with packages.

So, I've started from scratch by deleting the packages folder from my project. I would appreciate any assistance in getting this to work.

Here are my steps along with links to my error logs and package install logs.

***** Steps

1. Deleted the packages folder and rebuilt
   got 31 errors of packages that need to be installed [Problems01.txt](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12996208/Xamarin%20Problems/Problems01.txt)
2. Installed the first package in the list Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 which installed other dependencies as well. [packageinstall01.txt](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12996208/Xamarin%20Problems/packageinstall01.txt)
3. Tried to rebuild and got 9 errors having to do wiht missing packages [Problems02.txt](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12996208/Xamarin%20Problems/Problems02.txt)
4. Tried to install first package in Problems02.txt list (Xamarin.Android.Support), but it does not exist in nuget. But did find  Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView which is also in the list. So, I installed that.
5. Tried to rebuild - BUILD SUCCESS!!
6. Tried to run/debug in emulator using KitKat (4.4 XXHDP | Phone (Android 4.4 - API 19). this lead to the error:

System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.set_HorizontalTextAlignment' not found. on the line

```
LoadApplication(new App());
```

in the OnCreate method of the MainActivity class.

***** End Steps

Can anyone provide any guidance how to get this environment setup properly?  Please keep in mind that I am very novice with the Android side of this. Thanks!

Comment: check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/104444#Comment_104444

Comment: Hi Mate, thanks for the response. I made the changes suggested in the link, but the issue remains. Any other ideas?

Comment: @xgp Forms has a dependency on a _specific_ version of the Android Support Libraries.  As a result you should not install the Android Support Libraries first.  I would recommend installing Forms first and let it pull its dependencies, and then install any other packages after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working by:

1. Uninstalling VS 2015.
2. Uninstalling Xamarin Studio
3. Uninstalling anything having to do with Xamarin and Android Dev (there was an Android Studio installed)
4. Reinstalling Visual Studio 2015 including all the cross-platform features
5. Creating a new Xamarin.Forms (Portable) project
6. Grabbing the new Xamarin.Forms package from Nuget Libraries.

I can't be sure, but I suspect that there were conflicting files. Also, one additional step I had to do in my project was to remove the older Xamarin.Forms package folder from the Packages folder. Apparently, getting the update from Nuget didn't remove the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone provide any guidance how to get this environment setup properly? Please keep in mind that I am very novice with the Android side of this. Thanks!

From the error log, Xamarin forms packages may not be fully installed in your local machine. Some packages are missing. To resolve this problem, please try the following steps:

1. Close all Visual Studio instances.
2. Redirect to `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\` folder.
3. Rename or delete `Xamarin` folder
4. Open your solution with VS, rebuild the project.
5. Wait until VS finish downloading all the packages. It will take a few minutes depending on your local Net.